# Find matching puppeteer version for a given chromium version

Tags: version, puppeteer, chromium

I know puppeteer bundles a specific vsn of chromium.  I sort of need to go the other direction.  My company applies Linux distros that include chromium.  I need to take that version of chromium, and find the version of puppeteer that bundles that version of chromium.  How do I find that?

Answer (score 2):

See https://pptr.dev/chromium-support

(or source https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/chromium-support.md)

> ## Chromium Support
>
> The following versions of Chromium are supported, mapped to Puppeteer
> version:
>
> - Chromium 112.0.5614.0 - [Puppeteer v19.8.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v19.8.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 111.0.5556.0 - [Puppeteer v19.7.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v19.7.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 110.0.5479.0 - [Puppeteer v19.6.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v19.6.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 109.0.5412.0 - [Puppeteer v19.4.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v19.4.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 108.0.5351.0 - [Puppeteer v19.2.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v19.2.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 107.0.5296.0 - [Puppeteer v18.1.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v18.1.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 106.0.5249.0 - [Puppeteer v17.1.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v17.1.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 105.0.5173.0 - [Puppeteer v15.5.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v15.5.0/docs/api/index.md)
> - Chromium 104.0.5109.0 - Puppeteer v15.1.0

Answer (score -1):

goto node_modules/puppeteer/packages.json

Comment: This would give me the version of chromium bundled with puppeteer.  Not what I need.  I need to find the version of puppeteer that is guaranteed to work with a specific version of chromium.  To be clearer:  How do I find the version of puppeteer I should pair with chromium 79.0.3945.117-25.1